# Question about theorem for reduction of order!

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Theorem
Consider the n-th order homogeneous linear differential equation below,

$$a_0(x)\frac{d^ny}{dx^n}+a_1(x)\frac{d^{n-1}y}{dx^{n-1}}+...+a_{n-1}(x)\frac{dy}{dx}+a_n(x)y=0$$

Suppose $f$ is a **non trivial solution** to the above differential equation then with transformation y=f(x)v will reduce the above differential equation to the $n-1$th order homogeneous differential equation in the dependent variable $w=\frac{dv}{dx}$

Question:

1: What will happen if the solution is trivial?

What I understand by trivial is below
$y=c_1x+c_2x^2$

$c_1=c_2=0$ is the trivial solution to the above differential equation!(trivial seems to imply make everything zeroes)

2. If a non-trivial solution to the differential equation does not exist does that mean that we can't apply this theorem?
3. Base on my understanding on existence for uniqueness theorem for second order differential equation if $y(x_0)=0$, $y'(x_0)=0$ then we can conclude that $y(x)=0$. for $a \leq x \leq b$ If the I meet the condition that I state above does it mean reduction of order can't be carried out!
4. When does the theorem become totally invalid and how?

Thank you!

Comment: I think there is some confusion about what reduction of order is actually used for. Reduction of order is used to find another linearly independent solution to your ODE. So if $f = 0$, then $y = fv = 0v = 0$, and you _can't get an ODE in $v$ to solve for_, so you can't find another linearly independent solution $v$, making reduction of order useless for your problem. A similar idea goes for your second question: if a non-trivial solution doesn't exist, then reduction of order can't find one for you _because a non-trivial solution doesn't exist_.

Comment: Meaning our $f \neq 0$ in order for use to use the theorem stated above? Only for non-trivial case!